# Calculadora com Interface Gráfica Java

Tags: java, swing

Comecei a trabalhar com o framework Swing, criando uma calculadora com o `JOptionPane`, e consegui normalmente. Agora me foi lançado o desafio de inserir botões de <kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>*</kbd>, e <kbd>/</kbd> na calculadora, o problema é que eu pesquisei bastante e não estou conseguindo! Estou usando o `JButton` e não estou conseguindo saber o que fazer com ele.

Podem postar, se possível, o código completo com comentários me explicando o que faltou no meu, por favor.

**Como eu faço pra adicionar a função somar, subtrair, etc. aos botões?**

Por favor, se possível e necessário completar o código inteiro, expliquem o que faltou e o que eu devia fazer, pois quero aprender. Se preciso, postarei também o da última calculadora que fiz e deu certo usando apenas o `JOptionPane`.

Pois bem com a ajuda do @Deyel o meu código ficou assim:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Calculadora extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        private JButton botaoMais;
        private JButton botaoMenos;
        private JButton botaoVezes;
        private JButton botaoDividi;
        private JTextField campo;

    public Calculadora() {
        this.setTitle("Exemplo");
        this.setBounds(0,0,250,250);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        botaoMais = new JButton();
        botaoMais.setText("Soma");
        botaoMais.setBounds(30,60,60,30);
        this.add(botaoMais);

        botaoMenos = new JButton();
        botaoMenos.setText("Subtrai");
        botaoMenos.setBounds(30,60,60,30);
        this.add(botaoMenos);

        botaoVezes = new JButton();
        botaoVezes.setText("Multiplica");
        botaoVezes.setBounds(30,60,60,30);
        this.add(botaoVezes);

        botaoDividi = new JButton();
        botaoDividi.setText("Dividir");
        botaoDividi.setBounds(30,60,60,30);
        this.add(botaoDividi);

        campo = new JTextField();
        campo.setBounds(40,50,100,30);
        this.add(campo);

        botaoMais.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Primeiramente parabéns pela sua iniciativa perante ao resto da turma e, não menos importante, seja bem vindo a comunidade Stack Overflow!**

Agora vamos ao que interessa...

Percebi que o seu problema não está em criar os botões e a interface, e sim em adicionar uma função a eles, o que chamamos de eventos.

**Como os eventos funcionam:**

- Todo sistema operacional que suporta interface gráfica monitora
  eventos (cliques, movimentos do mouse, teclas pressionadas, etc.).
- Quando um evento acontece o sistema operacional informa ao
  programa.
- O programa decide o que fazer como evento de acordo como que
  foi programado.
- São os eventos que controlam todas as interações do usuário com o
  programa (cliques, texto digitado, movimentos do mouse, etc.).
- Para se trabalhar com eventos no Java a partir dos componentes
  SWING podemos utilizar funcionalidades do pacote `java.awt.event`.
- Cada componente da interface gráfica (janela, botão, campo de texto,
  etc.) conta com interfaces para ouvir (listen) quando um evento é
  gerado.
- Cada interface tem métodos associados para tratar os diferentes
  eventos.

Agora que a gente conhece um pouco melhor como os eventos funcionam, **vamos a parte prática!**

Escrevi esse exemplo que não possui muita utilidade, mas é ótimo para entender como os eventos funcionam na prática (observe os comentários):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MeuJFrame extends JFrame {

    private JButton botao;
    private JTextField campo;

    public MeuJFrame() {
        this.setTitle("Exemplo");
        this.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        botao = new JButton();
        botao.setText("botão");
        botao.setBounds(40, 100, 100, 50);
        this.add(botao);

        campo = new JTextField();
        campo.setBounds(40, 50, 100, 30);
        this.add(campo);

        // Adicionando um evento action ao botão
        botao.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                // Aqui você escreve qual será a ação do botão ao ser clicado!
                botao.setText(campo.getText());
            }
        });
    } // construtor

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MeuJFrame exemplo = new MeuJFrame();
        exemplo.setVisible(true);
    } // método main

} // classe
```

Se você executar o exemplo acima, vai perceber que a ação do botão que adicionei captura o texto inserido no `JTextField` e o atribui ao texto do botão.

**Um print da execução:**

[image: Um print da execução]

**Conclusão:**

Com as informações citadas acima, é possível inserir qualquer ação a qualquer botão do seu programa.

Não quis facilitar o seu desafio escrevendo como ficaria um botão de somar por exemplo porque é fazendo que se aprende!

Qualquer dúvida pergunte-me nos comentários, espero ter ajudado.

**EDIT:**

Como ainda restaram alguma dúvidas, resolvi escrever um protótipo de uma calculadora pra você possuir algo em que se basear:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Calculadora extends JFrame {

    private JButton numero1;
    private JButton numero2;
    private JButton somar;
    private JButton igual;
    private JTextField display;
    private int leitura;
    private int memoria;
    private char operacao;

    public Calculadora() {
        this.setTitle("Exemplo Botão Somar");
        this.setBounds(0, 0, 267, 235);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        leitura = 0;
        memoria = 0;

        somar = new JButton();
        somar.setText("+");
        somar.setBounds(145, 70, 78, 45);
        this.add(somar);

        igual = new JButton();
        igual.setText("=");
        igual.setBounds(25, 130, 200, 45);
        this.add(igual);

        numero1 = new JButton();
        numero1.setText("1");
        numero1.setBounds(25, 70, 45, 45);
        this.add(numero1);

        numero2 = new JButton();
        numero2.setText("2");
        numero2.setBounds(85, 70, 45, 45);
        this.add(numero2);

        display = new JTextField();
        display.setBounds(25, 25, 200, 30);
        this.add(display);

        numero1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                leitura *= 10;
                leitura += 1;
                display.setText(display.getText() + "1");
            }
        });

        numero2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                leitura *= 10;
                leitura += 2;
                display.setText(display.getText() + "2");
            }
        });

        somar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                operacao = '+';
                memoria += leitura;
                leitura = 0;
                display.setText("");
            }
        });

        igual.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                switch (operacao) {
                    case '+': {
                        memoria += leitura;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                leitura = 0;
                display.setText("" + memoria);
            }
        });
    } // construtor

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculadora exemplo = new Calculadora();
        exemplo.setVisible(true);
    }
} // classe
```

**Um print da execução:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: Ela não é perfeita, existem vários bugs propositais que você terá que solucionar para aprimorar sua lógica de programação... Utilize este código como ponto de partida!

Comment: Acredito que esteja caminhando bem, muito obrigado cara ! No entanto, a minha unica dúvida agora é: Como no seu exemplo, a ação do botão era capturar o texto, como eu faço para a ação de um botão ser soma, ou subtração para minha calculadora ? Veja, cheguei ate aqui:
  campo = new JTextField();
  campo.setBounds(40,50,100,30);
  this.add(campo);
  
  botaoMais.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

Agora só me falta saber como fazer a função ser soma ou qualquer outro elemento de uma calculadora em cada botão !

Comment: Explicar aqui pelos comentários é complicado... Adicionei um outro exemplo a minha resposta, mais parecido com uma calculadora. Qualquer dúvida me avisa!

Comment: Vou me esforçar ao máximo ! Muito obrigado, amigo ! Não tem ideia do quanto ajudou !

Comment: Isso ai! Aposto que você vai conseguir!!

Answer (score 3):

**Qual é a ideia do cálculo**

A ideia é pegar uma linguagem que tenha o método *eval* (como python e javascript), que é uma função que pega uma String, converte para uma linha de código e retorna o valor do resultado.

*(O "->" significa o retorno)*

> Exemplo1: `eval("5 + 5") -> 10`
>
> Exemplo2: `eval("10 / (5 + 5)") -> 1`
>
> Exemplo3: `eval("5 > 3") -> true`

**Como simular uma linguagem de Script**

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
int resultado = (Integer) engine.eval("5 + 5");
```

**getEngineByName("JavaScript");**
Vai nos retornar uma ScriptEngine, que nos permite usar códigos da linguage

**engine.eval("5 + 5");**
retorna o valor de 5 + 5

**(Se não deu pra entender minha explicação ou se precisa de mais alguma ajuda, por favor, me avise)**

Answer (score 0):

Segue o exemplo:

```
package fundamentos;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Calculadora extends JFrame {

    private JButton numero1;
    private JButton numero2;
    private JButton numero3;
    private JButton numero4;
    private JButton numero5;
    private JButton numero6;
    private JButton numero7;
    private JButton numero8;
    private JButton numero9;
    private JButton numero0;
    private JButton numeroP;
    
    private JButton dividir;
    private JButton multiplicar;
    private JButton subtrair;
    private JButton somar;
    private JButton igual;
    private JTextField display;
    
    private int leitura;
    private int memoria;
    private char operacao;

    public Calculadora() {
        this.setTitle("Exemplo Botão Somar");
        this.setBounds(500, 100, 292, 450);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        leitura = 0;
        memoria = 0;

        display = new JTextField();
        display.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 100);
        this.add(display);
        
        //FAIXA 01
        numero7 = new JButton();
        numero7.setText("7");
        numero7.setBounds(0, 120, 65, 65);
        this.add(numero7);
        
        numero4 = new JButton();
        numero4.setText("4");
        numero4.setBounds(0, 190, 65, 65);
        this.add(numero4);
        
        numero1 = new JButton();
        numero1.setText("1");
        numero1.setBounds(0, 260, 65, 65);
        this.add(numero1);
        
        numero0 = new JButton();
        numero0.setText("0");
        numero0.setBounds(0, 330, 65, 65);
        this.add(numero0);
        
        //FAIXA 02
        numero8 = new JButton();
        numero8.setText("8");
        numero8.setBounds(70, 120, 65, 65);
        this.add(numero8);
        
        numero5 = new JButton();
        numero5.setText("5");
        numero5.setBounds(70, 190, 65, 65);
        this.add(numero5);
        
        numero2 = new JButton();
        numero2.setText("2");
        numero2.setBounds(70, 260, 65, 65);
        this.add(numero2);
        
        numeroP = new JButton();
        numeroP.setText(".");
        numeroP.setBounds(70, 330, 65, 65);
        this.add(numeroP);
        
        //FAIXA 03
        numero9 = new JButton();
        numero9.setText("9");
        numero9.setBounds(140, 120, 65, 65);
        this.add(numero9);
        
        numero6 = new JButton();
        numero6.setText("6");
        numero6.setBounds(140, 190, 65, 65);
        this.add(numero6);
        
        numero3 = new JButton();
        numero3.setText("3");
        numero3.setBounds(140, 260, 65, 65);
        this.add(numero3);
        
        somar = new JButton();
        somar.setText("+");
        somar.setBounds(140, 330, 65, 65);
        this.add(somar);
        
        //FAIXA 04
        dividir = new JButton();
        dividir.setText("/");
        dividir.setBounds(210, 120, 65, 65);
        this.add(dividir);
        
        multiplicar = new JButton();
        multiplicar.setText("X");
        multiplicar.setBounds(210, 190, 65, 65);
        this.add(multiplicar);
        
        subtrair = new JButton();
        subtrair.setText("-");
        subtrair.setBounds(210, 260, 65, 65);
        this.add(subtrair);
        
        igual = new JButton();
        igual.setText("=");
        igual.setBounds(210, 330, 65, 65);
        this.add(igual);

        numero1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                leitura *= 10;
                leitura += 1;
                display.setText(display.getText() + "1");
            }
        });

        numero2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                leitura *= 10;
                leitura += 2;
                display.setText(display.getText() + "2");
            }
        });
        
        numero3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                leitura *= 10;
                leitura += 3;
                display.setText(display.getText() + "3");
            }
        });
        
        numero4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                leitura *= 10;
                leitura += 4;
                display.setText(display.getText() + "4");
            }
        });
        
        numero5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                leitura *= 10;
                leitura += 5;
                display.setText(display.getText() + "5");
            }
        });
        
        numero6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                leitura *= 10;
                leitura += 6;
                display.setText(display.getText() + "6");
            }
        });
        
        numero7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                leitura *= 10;
                leitura += 7;
                display.setText(display.getText() + "7");
            }
        });
        
        numero8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                leitura *= 10;
                leitura += 8;
                display.setText(display.getText() + "8");
            }
        });
        
        numero9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                leitura *= 10;
                leitura += 3;
                display.setText(display.getText() + "9");
            }
        });
        
        numero0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                leitura *= 10;
                leitura += 0;
                display.setText(display.getText() + "0");
            }
        });

        somar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                operacao = '+';
                memoria += leitura;
                leitura = 0;
                display.setText(memoria + " + ");
            }
        });
        
        subtrair.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                operacao = '-';
                memoria += leitura;
                leitura = 0;
                display.setText(memoria + " - ");
            }
        });
        
        multiplicar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                operacao = 'X';
                memoria += leitura;
                leitura = 0;
                display.setText(memoria + " X ");
            }
        });
        
        dividir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                operacao = '/';
                memoria += leitura;
                leitura = 0;
                display.setText(memoria + " / ");
            }
        });

        igual.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                switch (operacao) {
                    case '.': {
                        memoria = memoria + '.';
                        break;
                    }
                    case '+': {
                        memoria += leitura;
                        break;
                    }
                    
                    case '-': {
                        memoria -= leitura;
                        break;
                    }
                    
                    case 'X': {
                        memoria *= leitura;
                        break;
                    }
                    
                    case '/': {
                        memoria /= leitura;
                        break;
                    }
                    
                }
                leitura = 0;
                display.setText("" + memoria);
            }
        });
    } // construtor

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculadora exemplo = new Calculadora();
        exemplo.setVisible(true);
    }
} // classe
```