# Calculadora - operações com decimais

Tags: java

Mais uma vez apareço com essa calculadora aqui, já fui muito ajudado com ela e está quase pronta!

Está funcionando todas as operações perfeitamente, sem erro algum, exceto por um pequeno detalhe... ela só consegue fazer cálculos como `9+8`, `7*8`, etc.

Não consigo operar coisas como `18+30` que o resultado da `12`! `25+52` o resultado da `14`, e `23*2` o resultado da `10`...

Em alguns casos parece que ela soma os números decimais e depois opera pela unidade seguinte, em outros parece que faz uma loucura!.

O código segue abaixo.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Calculadora extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private JButton botaoMais;
    private JButton botaoMenos;
    private JButton botaoVezes;
    private JButton botaoDividi;
    private JButton botaoIgual;
    private JButton n1;
    private JButton n2;
    private JButton n3;
    private JButton n4;
    private JButton n5;
    private JButton n6;
    private JButton n7;
    private JButton n8;
    private JButton n9;
    private JButton n0;
    private char operacao;
    private JTextField campo;
    private int memoria;
    private int leitura;

    public Calculadora (){
        this.setTitle("Calculadora");
        this.setBounds(0,0,280,350);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        leitura = 0;
        memoria = 0;


    n1 = new JButton();
    n1.setText("1");
    n1.setBounds(25, 70, 45, 45);
    this.add(n1);

    n2 = new JButton();
    n2.setText ("2");
    n2.setBounds(85,70,45,45);
    this.add(n2);

    n3 = new JButton();
    n3.setText("3");
    n3.setBounds(140,70,45,45);
    this.add(n3);

    n4 = new JButton();
    n4.setText("4");
    n4.setBounds(25,125,45,45);
    this.add(n4);

    n5 = new JButton();
    n5.setText("5");
    n5.setBounds(85,125,45,45);
    this.add(n5);

    n6 = new JButton();
    n6.setText("6");
    n6.setBounds(140,125,45,45);
    this.add(n6);

    n7 = new JButton();
    n7.setText("7");
    n7.setBounds(25,180,45,45);
    this.add(n7);

    n8 = new JButton();
    n8.setText("8");
    n8.setBounds (85,180,45,45);
    this.add(n8);

    n9 = new JButton();
    n9.setText("9");
    n9.setBounds (140,180,45,45);
    this.add (n9);

    n0 = new JButton();
    n0.setText("0");
    n0.setBounds(140,235,45,45);
    this.add(n0);

    botaoIgual = new JButton();
    botaoIgual.setText ("=");
    botaoIgual.setBounds(25, 235, 106, 45);
    this.add(botaoIgual);

    botaoMais = new JButton();
    botaoMais.setText("+");
    botaoMais.setBounds(195, 70, 45, 45);
    this.add(botaoMais);

    botaoMenos = new JButton();
    botaoMenos.setText("-");
    botaoMenos.setBounds(195,125,45,45);
    this.add(botaoMenos);

    botaoVezes = new JButton();
    botaoVezes.setText("x");
    botaoVezes.setBounds(195,180,45,45);
    this.add(botaoVezes);

    botaoDividi = new JButton();
    botaoDividi.setText("/");
    botaoDividi.setBounds(195,235,45,45);
    this.add(botaoDividi);

    campo = new JTextField();
    campo.setBounds(25, 25, 215, 30);
    this.add(campo);

    n1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            leitura +=1;
            campo.setText(campo.getText()+ "1");


    }
  });
    n2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            leitura +=2;
            campo.setText(campo.getText()+ "2");
        }
    });
    n3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
            leitura +=3;
            campo.setText(campo.getText()+"3");
        }
    });
    n4.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            leitura+=4;
            campo.setText(campo.getText()+ "4");
        }
    });
    n5.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
            leitura+=5;
            campo.setText(campo.getText()+ "5");
        }
    });
    n6.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            leitura+=6;
            campo.setText(campo.getText()+"6");
        }
    });
    n7.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            leitura+=7;
            campo.setText(campo.getText()+ "7");

        }
    });
    n8.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            leitura+=8;
            campo.setText(campo.getText()+"8");

        }
    });
    n9.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            leitura+=9;
            campo.setText(campo.getText()+ "9");
        }
    });
    n0.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            leitura+=0;
            campo.setText(campo.getText()+ "0");
        }
    });
    botaoMais.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
            operacao = '+';
            if (memoria > 0){
                memoria += leitura;
            }else {
                memoria = leitura;
            }
            leitura = 0;
                    campo.setText("");
        }
    });
    botaoMenos.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
            operacao = '-';
            if(memoria > 0){
                memoria -= leitura;
            }else {
                memoria = leitura;
            }
            leitura = 0;
            campo.setText("");
        }
    });
    botaoVezes.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
            operacao = '*';
            if (memoria > 0){
                memoria *= leitura;
            }else {
                memoria = leitura;
            }
            leitura = 0;
            campo.setText("");
        }
    });
    botaoDividi.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
            operacao = '/';
            if (memoria > 0){
                memoria /= leitura;
            }else {
                memoria = leitura;
            }
            leitura = 0;
            campo.setText("");
        }
    });
    botaoIgual.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
            switch (operacao){
            case '+':{
                memoria +=leitura;
                break;
            }
            case '-':{
                memoria-=leitura;
                break;
            }
            case '*':{
                memoria *=leitura;
                break;
            }
            case '/':{
                memoria /=leitura;
                break;
            }
            }
            leitura = 0;
            campo.setText (""+ memoria);

        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculadora exemplo = new Calculadora();
        exemplo.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Primeiramente parabéns! Você chegou muito perto de uma implementação 100% funcional...**

Como eu mencionei em sua primeira pergunta ([Calculadora Eclipse Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12471/calculadora-eclipse-java/12476#12476)) ainda existiam alguns bugs a serem corrigidos. E um deles persistiu...

**O PROBLEMA**

Quando você clica em um botão numérico (<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd> etc.) você incrementa a variável `leitura` com o valor correspondente ao botão, certo?

Enquanto for digitado somente 1 dígito, tudo vai funcionar corretamente...

Porem, ao digitar 2 dígitos, **sua calculadora não está inserindo o valor das dezenas corretamente**, e sim, **apenas somando**, dessa forma:

> **A operação** 18 + 30 = 12 **pois** (1 + 8) + (3 + 0) = 12
>
> **A operação** 25 + 52 = 14 **pois** (2 + 5) + (5 + 2) = 14
>
> **A operação** 23 * 2 = 10 **pois** (2 + 3) * 2 = 10

**CORRIGINDO O PROBLEMA**

Come está (botão <kbd>1</kbd>):

```
n1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        leitura +=1;
        campo.setText(campo.getText()+ "1");
}
});

//para 1 clique: leitura = 1;
//para 2 cliques: leitura = 2;
//para 3 cliques: leitura = 3;
...
```

Como deveria ser (botão <kbd>1</kbd>):

```
n1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        leitura *= 10;  // faltou esse pequeno detalhe em seu código!
        leitura += 1;
        campo.setText(campo.getText()+ "1");
}
});

//para 1 clique: leitura = 1;
//para 2 cliques: leitura = 11;
//para 3 cliques: leitura = 111;
...
```

Faça esse ajuste em todos os botões numéricos e o problema será corrigido!

Qualquer dúvida pergunte nos comentários. Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Calculadora funcionando magnificamente ! Hoje na aula ao citar isso, terei de citar seu nome ! kkkk muito obrigado cara, de verdade ! Agora é hora de fazer e refazer até decorar pra que serve cada função, e tentar criar novos programas com essas funções ! Muito obrigado mesmo !

Comment: kkkkk disponha! :)