# Como atribuir ação a Imagem ou Botão

Tags: java, swing

Estou desenvolvendo a página inicial de um joguinho simples, oque desejo é adicionar um botão na tela onde ao clicar o jogo inicie, segue abaixo meu código de como estou montando o menu e trazendo o fundo, o código trás a imagem que coloquei como o botão, mas não estou conseguindo atribuir a ação de clique para o mesmo, não sei qual seria a melhor maneira de fazer isso, aceito ideias.

```
public Menu(){

        setFocusable(true);
        setDoubleBuffered(true);

        ImageIcon referencia = new ImageIcon("res\\images\\fundo.png");

        fundo = referencia.getImage();
        emJogo = true; //iniciar jogo
        timer = new Timer(5, this);
        timer.start();

        ImageIcon referencia2 = new ImageIcon("res\\images\\btn1.png");
        jogar = referencia2.getImage();

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){  

        Graphics2D graficos = (Graphics2D) g;
        graficos.drawImage(fundo, 0, 0, null);
        graficos.drawImage(jogar, 0, 0, null);

        g.dispose();

    }
```

Comment: Jbutton ? Se for, basta chamar o método actionperformed e inserir a ação nele. Veja um exemplo http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12471/calculadora-com-interface-gr%C3%A1fica-java/12476#12476

Comment: Tenta jogar a imagem num `JLabel`, só verifica se ela fica com os tamanhos certinhos e tal. `JLabel lb = new JLabel(referencia2);`. Se der certo eu posto uma resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Basta apenas registar um evento para teu botão como segue o exemplo abaixo e seja feliz.
A maioria dos componentes tem o método "addActionListener" para vincular o evento click.

```
// Adicionando um evento action ao botão
botao.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            // Aqui você escreve qual será a ação do botão ao ser clicado!
            botao.setText(campo.getText());
        }
    });
```